# Alphabetically sort in Angular

Tags: angular, sorting, alphabetical, alphabetical-sort

I am new in Angular and sorry if this question is repeated but I can't find the answer I was looking for. I have a file with a next JSON in it:

```
   {"name": "John", "size" : "small"},
   {"name": "Rocky", "size" : "small"},
   {"name": "Angel", "size" : "small"},
   {"name": "Amber", "size" : "small"},
   {"name": "Sam", "size" : "small"}
```

And I want to create a pipe so I could display **only names** but in alphabetical order.
That should look like this:

**Amber Angel John Rocky Sam**

Or maybe...is there any other way other than using the pipe?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Try `data.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name)).map(x => x.name)`

Comment: Hi @KunalMukherjee when I try it  I get this error:
HomeComponent.html:9 ERROR TypeError: data.sort is not a function
    at CitiesSortPipe.transform (cities-sort.pipe.ts:11)
    at checkAndUpdatePureExpressionInline (core.js:34390)
...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you want to create a pipe to do it, follow this code:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
  name: "nameConcat"
})
export class NamePipe implements Pipetransform {
  transform(value: any[], ...args: any[]) {
    const sorted = [...value].sort((a, b) => (a.name > b.name ? 1 : -1));
    return sorted.map((item) => item.name).join(" ");
  }
}
```

And use it like this:

```html
<p>{{data | nameConcat}}</p>
```

Here is a codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-bash-remov?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: I have a very similar solution that i created at one of my jobs, but note this only is an alphabetic sort.  If you want proper number sorting you would have to convert the values first.

Comment: Thanks to all but especially thanks for this answer. This really helped me.